# How to append integer value to JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, magento

I Used AJAX request to availability of Shop title of our system. In there i used use api and it response like this

```
"[{\"count\":2,\"seller_id_1\":\"1207\",\"title_1\":\"PRIMA CEYLON PVT
LTD\",\"url_1\":\"prima-ceylon-pvt-ltd\",\"seller_id_2\":\"6509\",\"title_2\":\"Prima
Management Services (Pvt)
Ltd\",\"url_2\":\"prima-management-services-pvt-ltd\"}]"
```

data retrieve using data response object's 0th element.

if response get 10 results (I means count of my response) that results generate 10 key value for title , url and seller_id .

that result following like this

title_1 : 
url_1
seller_id_1 :

title_2 : 
url_2
seller_id_2 :

when data catching i have to hard coded those things . So there is any mechanism to increment key value instead of hard coded.

I need to fetch value in as follow

```
json[0].title_1  

json[0].url_1

json[0].title_2  

json[0].url_2
```

Thank you

Comment: You can use `['title', 'url', seller'].for_each(prefix => ...` and a regular `for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)` to generate the keys ``` \`${prefix}_${i}\` ```.

Answer (score 0):

You can build an object with values as array of values of the variables.

> result[title][0] --> will be title_1 
>  result[title][1] -->
>   will be title_2

Similarly other values

```js
const [data] = JSON.parse(
  '[{"count":2,"seller_id_1":"1207","title_1":"PRIMA CEYLON PVTLTD","url_1":"prima-ceylon-pvt-ltd","seller_id_2":"6509","title_2":"Prima Management Services (Pvt)Ltd","url_2":"prima-management-services-pvt-ltd"}]'
);


const result = {
  'seller_id': [], 'title': [], 'url': []
};

for (let i = 1; i <= data.count; i++) {
  Object.keys(result).forEach(key => result[key].push(data[`${key}_${i}`]));
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var json = JSON.parse(
  '[{"count":2,"seller_id_1":"1207","title_1":"PRIMA CEYLON PVTLTD","url_1":"prima-ceylon-pvt-ltd","seller_id_2":"6509","title_2":"Prima Management Services (Pvt)Ltd","url_2":"prima-management-services-pvt-ltd"}]'
);

var i = 1;
var response_count = json[0].count;

  for (i = 1; i <= response_count; i++) {
    
    console.log(json[0]['url_' + i]);

  }
```